# sql select newer comments from a user's latest comment

Tags: mysql, sql

I probably want the impossible, but let's hope it's possible.

So, I want to get all the newer comments from a user's last comment date.

I don't think much sql details are needed.

1. A forum database for creating the forum topic (id, user_id, title, content, date)
2. A comment database (id, user_id (the user who comments), forum_id (which forum he comments to... Equal to id in forum database), date)

Any help would be much appreciated.

E.g.: Comment db:

```
 id user_id forum_id date 
  1       1        1 2018-12-16 14:00:00
  2       2        1 2018-12-16 14:50:00
  3       1        1 2018-12-16 15:35:00
  4       5        1 2018-12-16 16:50:00
  5       2        1 2018-12-16 17:50:00
```

Expected result:
Let' s say we want all the newer comments from user 1's last comment, so result should be id 4 and id 5, because they are newer comments to user_id 1.

Another example:

```
 id user_id forum_id date
  1       1        2 2018-12-16 18:10:00
  2       3        2 2018-12-16 19:25:00
  3       1        1 2018-12-17 10:00:00
```

Expected result:
We still want all the newer comments from user 1. The result should be id 2, because it's newer than his comment on forum_id 2.

Gordon's answer is great for solving first example with this:

```
select c.*
from comments c
where c.datetime > (select max(c2.datetime)
                from comments c2
                where c2.user_id = ?
               );
```

But it's not solving the other problem. If a user has the latest comment in the comment table, then this query won't give any results. But it can easily happen, that the given user have comments in other forum topics too, which have newer answers probably.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: If this sort of thing wasn't possible, it would severely curtail the usefulness of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select c.*
from comments c
where c.datetime > (select max(c2.datetime)
                    from comments c2
                    where c2.user_id = ?
                   );
```

`?` is for the parameter that describes the specific user.

Comment: Weird, I'm getting a syntax error. ...near 'comments c2 where c2.user_id = 3 ) '...

Comment: @Jones . . . There is no obvious syntax error in this answer.

Comment: I finally got to a PC, and it is indeed working. No idea why it showed an error on mobile.

Comment: This is incredible. I tried to solve this for over 2 months now. I am eternally grateful to you!

Comment: Unfortunately I realized, that this isn't perfect for me. If user 1 has the last comment in the database, then this query won't show anything, even if there are newer comments in another forum. I updated the question with more details on this one.

Comment: @Jones . . . There is no forum specified in this query, so it should pick up all later comments.